# custom field validation error does not show field name

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to implement a change password endpoint, 
I have this view:

```
 def update(self, request):
    user_data = {}
    classname = __class__.__name__
    function = 'update'
    try:
        user = request.user
        current = request.data['current']
        password = request.data['password']
        confirm = request.data['confirm']
        serializer = serializers.ChangePasswordSerializer(user, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(updated_by=request.user.username, updated_date=timezone.now())
            logger(request, msg=_("Added Successfully"), level="normal", classname=classname,
                   function=function,
                   user_data=user_data, status=status.HTTP_205_RESET_CONTENT)
            return Response({"message": _("Added Successfully")}, status=status.HTTP_205_RESET_CONTENT)
        logger(request, msg=serializer.errors, level="error", classname=classname, function=function,
               user_data=user_data, status=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
        return Response({'errors': serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)

    except Exception as ValidationError:
        return Response({"errors": _("Current password is not correct")}, status=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)

    except Exception as e:
        elogger(msg=e.args)
        return Response({"message": _("status500")}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

and this is my serializer:

```
 class ChangePasswordSerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):
     current = serializers.CharField()
     confirm = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, data):
        if data['current'] == data['password']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Password and Current password should not be the same")
        if data['confirm'] != data['password']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Password and Confirm password did not match")
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = ('password', 'current', 'confirm')
        validators = []

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        if not instance.check_password(validated_data.get('current')):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Current password is not correct")
        else:
            instance.set_password(validated_data['password'])
            instance.save()
        return instance
```

my first problem is that I get this validation error:

```
{
   "errors": {
      "non_field_errors": [
         "Password and Current password should not be the same"
      ]
   }
}
```

I want to have my field name instead of "non_field_errors", also I want my check password function be inside validate function but I dont know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the fields validation error you have to raise error from validate_fieldname function, ex- validate confirm password.

```
class ChangePasswordSerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):
    current = serializers.CharField()
    confirm = serializers.CharField()

    def validate_current(self, value):
        if value == self.initial_data['password']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Password and Current password should not be the same")
        return value

    def validate_confirm(self, value):
        if value != self.initial_data['password']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Password and Confirm password did not match")
        return value

    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = ('password', 'current', 'confirm')
        validators = []

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        if not instance.check_password(validated_data.get('current')):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Current password is not correct")
        else:
            instance.set_password(validated_data['password'])
            instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: could you please explain more? there are lots of answers to my questions but there is no example so I know how to implement it

Comment: I dont get the solution, first of all data['password'] is not true, there is no data in function, second here:        def validate_current(self, value):
          if value == data['password']:
             raise serializers.ValidationError("Password and Current password should not be the same")
          return value value is field current? how I can compare it with field passoword?

Comment: sorry i.e self.password

Comment: yeah I tried that but there is this error, and I still couldnt find the solution :Cannot call `.is_valid()` as no `data=` keyword argument was passed when instantiating the serializer instance.',

Comment: I found the answer to my error, I will edit your answer thank you for your help

Comment: there is another problem, no matter what you give as input it always return this function     def validate_confirm(self, value):
        if value != self.password:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Password and Confirm password did not match")
        return value

Comment: if value == self.password: here we have self.password and this condition always is false, I tried to print self.passowrd and it says invalid input

Comment: can you check in the constructor where we are setting the value, in that just check the value

Comment: i did this to get self.password value and the answer is none:    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.password = kwargs.get('password')
        raise serializers.ValidationError(self.password)
        super(ChangePasswordSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: I solved my problem and I will edit your answer.Thank you so much

Comment: can you please help me with this problem too?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56039788/how-to-use-check-password-inside-validate-function

Answer (score 1):

If you are raising validation error from ***`validate()`*** method, use a **`dict`** as error message,

```
msg = {"field_name_1": "Password and Confirm password did not match"}
raise serializers.ValidationError(msg)
```

---

#### code snippet

```
# serializer.py
class ChangePasswordSerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):
    foo = serializers.CharField()
    bar = serializers.IntegerField()

    # your code

    def validate(self, data):
        data = super().validate(data)
        errors = []
        if data['current'] == data['password']:
            msg_1 = {"field_name_1": "Password and Current password should not be the same"}
            errors.append(msg_1)

        if data['confirm'] != data['password']:
            msg_2 = {"field_name_2": "Password and Confirm password did not match"}
            errors.append(msg_2)
        if errors:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"errors": errors})
        return data
```

Comment: thats an interesting solution but the problem is here that how can I show both errors ? I mean sth like this: {
   "errors": {
      "field_name_2": [
         "Password and Confirm password did not match"
      ]      "field_name_1": [
         "some text"
      ]
   }
}

Comment: the output is this and its not true:{
   "errors": {
      "non_field_errors": [
         "field_name_1",
         "field_name_2"
      ]
   }
}

Comment: @Annabelle I've updated the code snippet...check now